# java regex match up to a string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Regex'ers:

How can I construct a Java Regex to match Strings lexigraphically <= to a given date string?

For example, suppose the input is in YYYY-DD-MM format:

```
2014-01-20 MLK day
2007-04-14 'twas a very good day
2014-05-19 is today
1998-11-30 someone's birthday
```

I'd like the filter to return all lines before, say, Groundhog's day of this year, 2014-02-20;
so in the above list the regex would return all lines except today.  (I don't want to convert the
dates to Epoch time; I'd like to just pass a Regex to a class that runs a map/reduce job so that
my input record reader can use the Regex as it constructs bundles to deliver to the mappers.)

TIA,

Comment: why regex why not date parsing ?

Comment: It would be better to use a parser instead.

Comment: Regrettably, the team that designed the input record reader class only supplied a method to add a Regex.  Yes, I could rewrite this, but that class does a huge amount of otherwise useful work.

Comment: That way lies madness.  The team that designed the class messed up and needs to provide the requisite API to support the use case.  You need a chisel and you've been provided with a screwdriver.  It is not your responsibility to "make do" with the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's near impossible to do `<=` type logic with regular expressions.  You technically could, but you'd have to map out every possible scenario...and then if you want to change the date you are comparing to, the whole expression would change.  Instead, I'd just match all the dates/values and then use a date parser to see if it less then the date.  Here's [an expression to get you started](http://regex101.com/r/kL2mE4):

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(.*)
```

Then the date will be in capture group one.  If it is `<=` Groundhog's day, then you have the value in capture group two.

---

To show how complicated it is to do `<=` logic with regular expression, I [whipped together a quick expression](http://regex101.com/r/mF8cL0) to match numbers `> 0` and `<= 27`.

```
^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-7])$
```

As you can see, we pretty much need to map out each scenario.  You can imagine how much more of a headache this would be with a date..and you wouldn't just be able to say "2014-02-02", you'd need to redo the majority of the expression.